# iOS load my tweets that have been favorited by other users

Tags: ios, twitter

In the twitter application, the mentions section not only displays @username mentions, but it also displays when one of your tweets have been favorited by someone else.

I have been pouring over the Twitter Rest API and looking through there forums, but I cannot find a way to mimic this behavior.

the only options for favorites I can find are to load a users favorites, create, or destroy.

Anyone know of a way to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for the GET statuses/user_timeline request?  It includes "favorited" in the results.

Comment: This simply lets you know if the current tweet has been favorited or not, but not who favorited the tweet. The idea is to display to the user who favorited your tweet and what tweet it was.